# Codeigniter how to order by this query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

this is my query where i show only 9 rows but whow to order by date
how and where i should add my (order by in the current query)

```
$q = $this->db->get('exchange_rate, country', 9,'exchange_rate.CountryId = country.CountryId');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->from('exchange_rate');
$this->db->join('country', 'exchange_rate.CountryId = country.CountryId');
$this->db->limit(9);
$this->db->order_by("date", "asc");
$query = $this->db->get();
```

For more information go to codeigniter [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: this worked fine, i appreciate your help 

how can i set where condition for example active = 1

Comment: $this->db->where('active', 1);

Answer (score 0):

try this format, just as an example

```
         $this->db->select('a.exchange_rate, b.country');
         $this->db->from('exchange_rate a');
         $this->db->join('country b','b.CountryId = a.CountryId');
         $this->db->order_by("yourOrderByColumn",'DESC');
         $this->db->limit(9);
         $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: *but here i don't know how to set the rows to show only 9 it shows my all rows*

Comment: don't know who to do that??!

Comment: how i can accept some one answer it this was working, to let the answer is solved

Answer (score 0):

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

you will get good idea about codeignitor databse conceepts

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using the [`get()` method](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) terribly wrong. Where you got that syntax, I have no idea.

Since `get()` is a method that triggers the query, all parameter methods that add your query's details - like `where()`, `order_by()`, etc. - should come *before* it.

```
$this->db->order_by('column', 'ASC');
$this->db->get('table_name');
```

I'd also recommend using a JOIN instead of selecting two tables with a weird `WHERE` sequence.

```
$this->db->select('column, another_column, etc');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->join('another_table', 'another_table.column = table.column');
$this->db->order_by('sort', 'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Please check the answer as the solution if it worked for you.